# best way to save textdata in android?

Tags: android, textview

what's the best way to save texts in an android app? i wan't to create a book-app and i was wondering, what would be the best way to save the text-data, which is displayed later on the pages? there will be no user editing of the text, just for reading purpose. xml, @string, String[], database, ...? it's going to be about 900 words / 6000 characters (with blankspaces).

thx b

Comment: Save where? What's the purpose?

Comment: there is no best way, all up to you. You shouldn't ask opinion-based questions here.

Comment: save within the app, so the app can display them on the "bookpages". i am talking about the storytext.

Comment: sorry, i'm quiet new to android, i didn't want to ask for an opinion, i just want to know what's the general way for this kind of data and usage.

Answer (score 1):

We have lots of ways which you can use them and all of them are good and sufficient for regular applications. I indicate some of them here:

1. You can use xml file and save your text as String there. (Best for limited text and medium range text)
2. SQLite Database. A kind of offline database which you can trying to saving your text data even with unique id's and when you need your text, just use a query to fetch them. Attention: Use TEXT data-type.
3. String variables: "A kind of foolish way!"

Answer (score 1):

Usually e-book is a file of txt/fb/pdf/etc. format. Thats actually the answer to your question).
If you are going to operate with small texts (which are not books) its up to you how to store it. It could be sqlite db, Realm.io db (both are most applicable for small texts), SharedPreferences or files. Realm is fast no-sql db engine, sqlite is built-in solution but requires lots of boilerplate code, SharedPrefs and File requires to implement some async way to store/restore to avoid UI lagging/freezing.